# What is the meaning of 수상 in 수상보안​간부학교?

Tags: north-korean, names

I guess, 수상보안​간부학교 is the school name. What does 수상 mean? I searched in the dictionary, and it has several usages. I doubt that it means senior school or prize-awarded school. Does somebody know?

Comment: Given the military context (보안, 간부), I guess it means maritime.

Comment: According to this: http://encykorea.aks.ac.kr/Contents/Item/E0066450, 보안​간부학교 is a type of military school. May be 수상 here is just the name for one of such schools

Comment: [수상(水上)](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=RvfcDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA702&lpg=PA702#v=onepage&q&f=false) relates to water and waters. [This blog post](https://m.blog.naver.com/korea213/80054338721) says "**해군**분야 전문인력을 양성하기 위해 47.6 나진에 설립된 「수상보안간부학교」...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

수상 literally means 'on the water' because 수 means water and 상 means on or above. 수상 is usually used as a prefix meaning maritime or naval. 보안 means security, 간부 means officer, 학교 means school. 보안간부학교, however, was used in mid-20th century North Korea to mean a military school to educate military officers. 수상보안간부학교 then means Naval Academy.

Answer (score 0):

According to the google search by the name, it seems it's North Korea's military academy for their version of coast guard.

수상, 보안, 간부, 학교... These words are still in daily use in South Korea, but we never use them together in this combination.
수상 = related to water
보안 = security
간부 = officers
학교 = school